# Lavorare ai locomotori: cosa significa?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Storia del nuovo cognome* di Elena Ferrante, ho trovato l'espressione in oggetto che mi è poco chiara. Ci sono due frasi che usano la stessa espressione:

p. 457

> Chiesi di Enzo. Disse che lavorava ai locomotori, usò quell'espressione, e capii presto che credeva che lui e Lila fossero sposati, definì Enzo con simpatia e rispetto "il signor Cerullo".

p. 464

> vidi Enzo seduto sul letto, fiaccato dalla fatica ai locomotori di chissà quale fabbrica;

Al primo momento, visto che Enzo e Lila abitano a San Giovanni a Teduccio di Napoli in anni 60-70 e Enzo faceva lavori semplici in altre pagine, ho immaginato che lui lavorasse nell'Officine di Pietrarsa dove produceva locomotive e binari, ma col secondo esempio d'uso, non ne sono più sicuro.

Grazie in anticipo.

Comment: Forse è un refuso? Mi sembra più sensato _fiaccato dalla fatica ai locomotori_

Comment: Giusto, ora correggo, grazie.

Answer (score 2):

Solitamente [locomotore](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/locomotore/) è sinonimo di locomotiva, cioè la macchina alimentata elettricamente, a vapore oppure Diesel che viene usata per trainare i treni.

In senso più generale una macchina locomotrice è un dispositivo che è deputato al movimento o allo spostamento di qualcosa.

Ad esempio nelle fabbriche della cosiddetta industria pesante come le acciaierie, spesso vengono usati treni perché la banda stagnata in uscita dall’altoforno viene prodotta in rotoli che pesano diverse tonnellate.

In questi casi è necessario utilizzare locomotive Diesel per avere la potenza sufficiente per portare il prodotto fuori dalla fabbrica e verso la destinazione finale.

Tornando al passaggio da te citato è anche possibile che il protagonista non costruisca locomotori ma lavori in una fabbrica dove è necessario usarli a causa del peso delle merci da movimentare.

Comment: Grazie per la risposta. Secondo te, il protagonista potrebbe lavorare come uno che scarica e carica prodotti e materie presso una linea di collegamento, cioè quel treno che parte da una fabbrica e arriva su binari di ferrovie, in qualche fabbrica? Comunque questa espressione mi suona un po' strano tutto ora.

Comment: Potrebbe benissimo essere così.